# How to create HelloWorld Zend Soap Server & Client over SSL using Self Signed Certificate

Tags: zend-framework, soap, openssl

I am trying to create a basic SOAP Server over SSL. Before making Web Services available on my Production website, I have to test it on Development system with has got Self Signed Certificate (Whose authentication is a problem right now). Following are the problems I am facing in that regard:

1. When I try to call https://zendsoap.lan/Zend_Soap_server.php?wsdl
   its works fine I can view the wsdl.
2. But when I try https://zendsoap.lan/Zend_Soap_server.php, I get
   this:

> SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from
>       'https://zendsoap.lan/Zend_Soap_Server.php?wsdl' : failed to load
>       external entity "https://zendsoap.lan/Zend_Soap_Server.php?wsdl"

Is that something I should be getting or Some nice looking HTML page
    describing the usage of webservice like in NuSoap.

I tried verify_peer=>false as I am running it on dev server so no need to verify my own created certificate, but obviously on production I want the Certificate to be verified.
This thing **work fine with NuSoap** but most of the stuff in NuSoap is deprecated for our server which is running PHP 5.4.6, So the most reliable solution for me using PHP's SOAP extension. And the reason for me using Zend is we're in process of moving our system from some third party framework to Zend Framework and everyday I get requests from client to add this & that new components, I assumed if I develop every new request from Client using Zend libraries then it will be easy for me in later stages to move to Zend Framework.

openssl is enable and tried with defining local_cert as well, but no Joy.

I hope I made some sense there.

**Basically looking for some instruction how to create Self Signed Certificates for this purpose, what should be the code for Server & Client.**

Comment: Can you provide the wsdl definition.